# UWP - How to start multiple tasks running in parallel?

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, xaml, uwp

I have an app where I select multiple (300-500) images then create a video where each image is a frame. In order to load these images into a composition for playback, I need to convert them and save them to temporary memory before they can be loaded. This conversion/save process is taking some time and I'm trying to find ways to speed up the task.

What would be a good way to have multiple instances of this conversion task take place in parallel? Currently, CPU usage is low (4%-6%) while the conversion is taking place.

Here is how I'd like it to work:

1. User picks multiple image files
2. A folder in temporary storage is created
3. Multiple image convert/save tasks are created and run in parallel.
4. After conversion and save is complete, all converted images in temporary storage folder are selected and loaded into a composition for playback.

Here's what I have now:

```
private async Task OpenImageSequence(IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> files)
{

    destFolder = await ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.CreateFolderAsync(NameNoExt, CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
    var composition = new MediaComposition();

    foreach (StorageFile file in files)
    {
        CreateImage(file);
    }

    IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> fileList = await destFolder.GetFilesAsync();

    foreach (StorageFile imgFile in fileList)
    {
        var clip = await MediaClip.CreateFromImageFileAsync(imgFile, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(frameIncrement));
        composition.Clips.Add(clip);
    }

    MediaStreamSource newImageSequence = composition.GenerateMediaStreamSource(defaultProfile);
    windowsSource = MediaSource.CreateFromMediaStreamSource(newImageSequence);

}

private async Task CreateImage(StorageFile file)
{
    var stream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
    
    //....Image Conversion Code....//

    var destFile = await destFolder.CreateFileAsync("exrConvert.png", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);

    await canvas.SaveAsync(destFile.Path.ToString(), CanvasBitmapFileFormat.Png);
}
```

Basically I'd like to have as many instances of the the CreateImage task running in parallel as possible. Any thoughts as to how I go about doing this?

I tried the following for a selection of 10 images but the images did not seem to be processed in parallel:

```
    Task t1 = CreateImage(files.ElementAt(0));
    Task t2 = CreateImage(files.ElementAt(1));
    Task t3 = CreateImage(files.ElementAt(2));
    Task t4 = CreateImage(files.ElementAt(3));
    Task t5 = CreateImage(files.ElementAt(4));
    Task t6 = CreateImage(files.ElementAt(5));
    Task t7 = CreateImage(files.ElementAt(6));
    Task t8 = CreateImage(files.ElementAt(7));
    Task t9 = CreateImage(files.ElementAt(8));
    Task t10 = CreateImage(files.ElementAt(9));

    await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8, t9, t10);
```

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: Your code is IO bound, not CPU bound, so you're only going to have high CPU utilization if you're doing something wrong.  You need to look at your utilization of the location(s) you're reading/writing files on.   Most file storage devices don't parallelized well, so you're unlikely to see significant improvements (and can in fact see significant degradation) from parallelization.

Comment: As a correlation to Servy's comment, your best bet for making it faster is probably to tradeoff memory. I.e., keep streams in memory rather than using a temporary directory.

Comment: Thank you both for the clarifying the problem for me. I had been keeping the streams in memory but kept running into issues when creating a media composition. I'll pursue that further though as it seems to be the best path forward. If I were to keep the streams in memory, would there be a benefit to parallelization of the image conversion task since there would no longer be the bottle neck of storage device performance?

Comment: You mentioned "but the images did not seem to be processed in parallel", is it still a task-by-task processing or the CreateImage method not actually running?

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1):

To let multiple tasks run in parallel, each task have to be composed as a background task. So you need to use [Task.Run()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=netcore-3.1#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_Run_System_Action_) or something. Plain async function with Task return type does not yield background task.

```
//foreach (StorageFile file in files)
//{
//    await CreateImage(file);
//}
var tasks_in_background_thread = files.Select(file => Task.Run(async () =>
{
    await CreateImage(file);
}));
await Task.WhenAll(tasks_in_background_thread);
```